# How to get data from JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I am new in Java and I try to search and try many ways to get `USER_NAME` and `PASSWORD` in `JSONObject`
here my code:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONObject input = inputHeader.generateInputHeader("ABCD001");
JSONObject jsonResponse = requestService.startRequestTransactionHttp(input);

if(jsonResponse.getString("RES_ID").toString().equals("000")) {
      //here I want get USER_NAME and PASSWORD
}
```

Here is what `jsonResponse` respond

```
{  "RES_ID" : "000",  "DATA" : {    "PASSWORD" : "123456",    "USER_NAME" : "abcd"  },  "RES_MSG" : "OK!"}
```

please help me to solve it.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: This code i removed what I try, but I want get `USER_NAME` in block `if RES_ID =000`

Comment: so what is the problem, why you're not able to do it?

Comment: @Math277 I'm not sure, what are you talking about. How would removing code will give you expected output ?

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for trying help. what I want is how to access `USER_NAME` . follow answer of @RishikeshDhokare , I can solve my problem

Comment: @Math277 I don't understand, you already coded same, so what was new in that ?

Comment: @Math277 if an answer serves your purpose, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html), you should use:

```
JSONObject data = jsonResponse.getObject("DATA");
String username = data.getString("USER_NAME");
String password = data.getString("PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to access the nested objects -

```
JSONObject data= jsonResponse.getJSONObject("DATA");
data.getString("USER_NAME");
data.getString("PASSWORD");
```